# Random ints in an array and arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

So i have two methods to create a randomized array and arraylist with 100 random integers. For some reason only the arraylist works though. Not sure what is wrong. Can someone take a look at it? I really don't know why it doesn't work. Is there a better way to randomize an array?

```
public static int[] gen1()
  {
    int[] no = new int[100];
    for(int i=0;i<no.length;i++)
    {
        no[i] =(int)(Math.random());
    }
    return no;
}   

public static ArrayList<Integer> gen2()
{
    ArrayList<Integer> oh = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        oh.add(random.nextInt());
    }
    return oh;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{   
    System.out.println("Original Array:");
    System.out.println(gen1());
    System.out.println("Original List:");
    System.out.println(gen2());
}
```

Comment: Why `(int)(Math.random())` in one case and `Random#nextInt` in the other? What does `Math.random()` do? Why do you think so?

Answer (score 0):

`Math.random()` returns a `double` between 0 and 1 (exclusive), so casting it to int will always return 0. That's the reason your array will contain only 0s.

On the other hand, `random.nextInt()`, used to populate the `ArrayList` can return any of the possible `int` values.

Comment: Ok, what do i use then? How do I put random ints into my array?

Comment: @user5344755 Use the same code you used for generating random ints for the ArrayList.

Comment: I just tried this and it still didn't work...

     public static int[] gen1()
 {
  Random random = new Random();
  int[] no = new int[100];
  for(int i=0;i<no.length;i++)
  {
   no[i] =random.nextInt();
  }
  return no;
 }

Comment: @user5344755 You haven't defined _didn't work_. Are you just having trouble printing the array?

Comment: @user5344755 What do you mean by doesn't work? You should note that `System.out.println(gen1());` is not the correct way to print an array. Try `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(gen1()));`

Comment: It wasn't printing out correctly I guess. I got it to work thank you.